# Animation not running in Windows 8.1 app using DispatcherTimer

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I have a simple `Storyboard` that rotates a grid to 60 degrees and then back to 0 but the animation is not running and I cant figure out why. Im using a `DispatcherTimer` to make sure it runs at set intervals. Ive also tried creating the `Storyboard` in xaml and calling `Storyboard.Begin()` from Ticker event but no luck. Thanks in advance.
When debugging and I add a breakpoint to Ticker event the animation runs

MainPage.cs

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private DispatcherTimer timer;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += (s, args) =>
        {
            timer = new DispatcherTimer();

            timer.Tick += Ticker;
            timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 6);
            timer.Start();                
        };

    }

    public void Ticker(object sender, object e)
    {
        var sb = new Storyboard();
        var animation2 = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
        var ease0 = new EasingDoubleKeyFrame() { KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0)), Value = 0 };
        var ease1 = new EasingDoubleKeyFrame() { KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2500)), Value = 40 };
        var ease2 = new EasingDoubleKeyFrame() { KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(4000)), Value = 60 };
        var ease3 = new EasingDoubleKeyFrame() { KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(4100)), Value = 0 };
        animation2.KeyFrames.Add(ease0);
        animation2.KeyFrames.Add(ease1);
        animation2.KeyFrames.Add(ease2);
        animation2.KeyFrames.Add(ease3);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation2, "(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)");
        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation2, grid2);
        sb.Children.Add(animation2);

        sb.Completed += (se, argss) =>
        {

        };
        sb.Begin();            
    }
```

MainPage.xaml

```
 <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">       
        <Grid x:Name="grid2" Width="250" Height="250" Background="Blue" Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid.Projection>
                <PlaneProjection/>
            </Grid.Projection>
        </Grid>      
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

You can use [BeginTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.timeline.begintime.aspx) and [Duration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.duration.aspx) to set timeline for animation.

I have used begintime instead of timer.below code working fine here.

```
  protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var sb = new Storyboard();
        var animation2 = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
        animation2.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(6);
        var ease0 = new EasingDoubleKeyFrame() { KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0)), Value = 0 };
        var ease1 = new EasingDoubleKeyFrame() { KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2500)), Value = 40 };
        var ease2 = new EasingDoubleKeyFrame() { KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(4000)), Value = 60 };
        var ease3 = new EasingDoubleKeyFrame() { KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(4100)), Value = 0 };
        animation2.KeyFrames.Add(ease0);
        animation2.KeyFrames.Add(ease1);
        animation2.KeyFrames.Add(ease2);
        animation2.KeyFrames.Add(ease3);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation2, "(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)");
        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation2, grid2);
        sb.Children.Add(animation2);

        sb.Completed += (se, argss) =>
        {

        };
        sb.Begin();
    }
```

Same animation you can implement using xaml also.

```
 <Grid Background="Black">
    <Grid x:Name="grid2" Width="250" Height="250" Background="Blue" Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.Projection>
            <PlaneProjection/>
        </Grid.Projection>
        <Grid.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames EnableDependentAnimation="True" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid2">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="0"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="40"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.9" Value="60"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="0"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Grid.Triggers>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. This doesnt fix the problem of running the Storyboard at set intervals with the DispatcherTimer though as it just runs once.